# How can I add prepare statement in my comment printing system

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm currently building a system where users can write and read comments. So the comments will be inserted into database (the inserting part is already protected with the prepared statement), so now I want to add the prepared statement at the comment printing part too.

This is the comment inserting part

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $nickname=$_POST['user_nickname'];
    $email=$_POST['user_email'];
    $comment=$_POST['cmt_text'];
    $course=$_POST['user_course'];
    $rating=$_POST['user_rating'];
    $classof=$_POST['user_classof'];
    $school_id=$_POST['id'];
    $db="INSERT INTO comments(user_nickname,user_email,cmt_text,user_course,user_rating,school_id,user_classof) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    $stmt=mysqli_stmt_init($con);
    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$db)){
        echo "Data Error";
    }else{
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ssssiii", $nickname,$email,$comment,$course,$rating,$school_id,$classof);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }
    header("location:Done.php");
    exit;
    }?>
```

And this is where I want to add prepared statements

```
<?php 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE school_id=$sid ORDER BY Datetime DESC ";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    ?>
        <div class="single-item">
            <h4><?php echo $row['user_nickname'];   ?></h4>
            <p><?php echo $row['Datetime']; 
            ?></p>
            <p><b>Course</b> : <?php echo $row['user_course']; 
            ?></p>
            <p><b>Class of</b> <?php echo $row['user_classof']; 
            ?></b></p>
            <p><b>Rating : </b><?php echo $row['user_rating']; 
            ?>/5</p>
            <p><b>Comment : </b><?php echo $row['cmt_text']; 
            ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php
            }
        }
?>
```

I have tried adding, but I got stuck when it comes to the part where I need to put the parameter, since I am printing out all the comments, how can I add the `?` parameter?

By the way, `$sid` is a specific id for one school. There's more than a hundred schools in the`comments`  table. I put all the comments from every schools in one table.

Comment: i think there no need prepare statement in SELECT for print comments.

Comment: Oh, I thought so, thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a function in which you will prepare the data.

```
function selectComments(mysqli $mysqli, ?int $schoolId = null): array
{
    if ($schoolId) {
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM comments WHERE school_id=? ORDER BY Datetime DESC');
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $schoolId);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
    } else {
        $result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY Datetime DESC');
    }
    return $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
foreach(selectComments($con, $sid) as $row) {
    // your HTML table
}
```

Comment: Hi, I applied it and it worked, but may I know what the ```mysqli $mysqli, ?int $schoolId = null``` is doing? If I replaced it with just two parameters ```($mysqli,$schoolId)``` will there be any problem?

Comment: That's called parameter type hinting. It specifies what is the allowed type of the value being passed in.